# pass lxml variable as xml in python in curl command

Tags: python, curl, lxml

Following command is working through Unix terminal :

```
 curl  -v -k  --data-binary @./SampleRequest_OFFSHORE.xml https://world-service-dev.intra.aexp.com:4414/worldservice/CLIC/CaseManagementService/V1
```

But when I pass the same command through python , I am getting an error , as I am not able to pass the request variable properly here . My python code :

```
from lxml import etree
```

`tree = etree.parse(template_xml)`

```
//Modified tree variable in my code and making the following call 
response = subprocess.check_output(["curl", "-k",'-v', '--data-binary' , etree.tostring(tree), "https://world-service-dev.intra.aexp.com:4414/worldservice/CLIC/CaseManagementService/V1"])
```

Can you please help me to pass the etree.tostring(tree)  properly in the code .

Comment: what does `etree.tostring(tree)` look like?

Comment: It is a soap request .

'<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:cre="http://www.americanexpress.com/worldservice/CLIC/CaseManagementService/V1/createCase" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v4="http://www.americanexpress.com/worldservice/ServiceHeader/V4"> <header> <body>'

Comment: "Getting an error" -- what error, specifically?

Comment: Error comes after making a call to the backend successfully .
It is basically the Data power webservice I am calling , doesnt identify the request parameters and throws away the following response code : 'Error 0x00d30003 Rejected by policy'

Comment: If the request is actually going through to the backend, you should use a packet sniffer or similar tool to determine how the request differs when you pass a filename vs when curl is invoked from Python, then ask a StackOverflow question about that difference once you've identified it. A question that can only be reproduced with a backend only you have access to is a question other folks are unlikely to be able to help with in a productive manner.

Comment: thanks Charles..I will get back with a proper Question and more information .

Comment: From the docs _"If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a file name to read the data from, or - if you want curl to read the data from stdin."_. How about swithcing to `subprocess.Popen` using `'--data-binary', '-'` and then `communicate(etree.tostring(tree)`)`?